# How to mock a service (or a ServiceProvider) when running Feature tests in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mocking, phpunit

I'm writing a small API in Laravel, partly for the purposes of learning this framework. I think I have spotted a gaping hole in the docs, but it may be due to my not understanding the "Laravel way" to do what I want.

I am writing an HTTP API to, amongst other things, list, create and delete system users on a Linux server. The structure is like so:

- Routes to `/v1/users` connect `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` verbs to controller methods `get`, `create` and `delete` respectively.
- The controller `App\Http\Controllers\UserController` does not actually run system calls, that is done by a service `App\Services\Users`.
- The service is created by a ServiceProvider `App\Providers\Server\Users` that registers a `singleton` of the service on a deferred basis.
- The service is instantiated by Laravel automatically and auto-injected into the controller's constructor.

OK, so this all works. I have also written some test code, like so:

```
public function testGetUsers()
{
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/v1/users');
    /* @var $response \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse */

    $response
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson(['ok' => true, ]);
}
```

This also works fine. However, this uses the normal bindings for the `UserService`, and I want to put a dummy/mock in here instead.

I think I need to change my `UserService` to an interface, which is easy, but I am not sure how to tell the underlying test system that I want it to run my controller, but with a non-standard service. I see `App::bind()` cropping up in Stack Overflow answers when researching this, but `App` is not automatically in scope in artisan-generated tests, so it feels like clutching at straws.

How can I instantiate a dummy service and then send it to Laravel when testing, so it does not use the standard ServiceProvider instead?

Comment: Why do you test service provider? Service provider has two functions `boot()` and `register()`, what is there to test. Its all tested in Laravel tests. You need to test the class that service provider instantiates.

Comment: @Kyslik: I don't want to test the service provider (or the service). I just want to swap the service for a dummy so I can test the system with a dummy service (using the real service in this case would make it an integration test, and I just want a self-contained feature test).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The obvious way is to re-bind the implementation in `setUp()`.

Make your self a new `UserTestCase` (or edit the one provided by Laravel) and add:

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        app()->bind(YourService::class, function() { // not a service provider but the target of service provider
            return new YourFakeService();
        });
    }
}

class YourFakeService {} // I personally keep fakes in the test files itself if they are short
```

---

Register providers conditionally based on environment (put this in **AppServiceProvider.php** or any other provider that you designate for this task - **ConditionalLoaderServiceProvider.php** or whatever) in `register()` method

```
if (app()->environment('testing')) {
    app()->register(FakeUserProvider::class);
} else {
    app()->register(UserProvider::class);
}
```

> **Note**: drawback is that *list* of providers is on two places one in config/app.php and one in the AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: Ha ha, very similar to mine, posted just now! Thank you for this. I got mine through a mixture of auto-complete and guessing, rather than hard-won experience `:-)`. I'll take a look at moving my binding to `setUp()` rather than doing it in each test though - good idea.

Comment: @halfer Yea I see, good job! PHPStorm rocks :). Do that, create UserTestCase as I suggest and include the `setUp()` there. Problem with this is that when you need more than one *re-binding* you will end up mixing stuff up, so I'd suggest the conditional registering providers.

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks. I'm intrigued by the function `app()` - is that a global, and is that different in some way to using `$this->app`? Naked functions feel a bit odd to me in classes, but I wonder if this is a Laravel thing that I just need to adjust to.

Comment: @halfer Yea its a Laravel thing, there is plenty helpers that actually help :) see this [file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php). For example I do not use `app()->make(A::class)` but `resolve(A::class)` which is `app(A::class)`, or sometimes when I do not inject `Request` I simply use `request()` (if user is logged in I can access the instance via `request()->user()`), or `abort(...)`, or `route('route.name.here')`... I sometimes make my own helper.php file and autoload it the same way how Laravel does it.

Comment: Interesting. I like how the func definitions check to see if they exist already, so if they have been overridden, the custom implementation will be preferred. Alright, this has got me moving again - I appreciate your help.

Comment: @halfer If you are really new to Laravel pick up some free courses on laracasts.com - **Whats new in Laravel** are really good ones or [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017) - I am not sure what is free / paid. Good Luck.

Answer (score 6):

Aha, I have found a temporary solution. I'll post it here, and then explain how it can be improved.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use \App\Services\Users as UsersService;

class UsersTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Checks the listing of users
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testGetUsers()
    {
        $this->app->bind(UsersService::class, function() {
            return new UsersDummy();
        });

        $response = $this->json('GET', '/v1/users');

        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson(['ok' => true, ]);
    }
}

class UsersDummy extends UsersService
{
    public function listUsers()
    {
        return ['tom', 'dick', 'harry', ];
    }
}
```

This injects a DI binding so that the default ServiceProvider does not need to kick in. If I add some debug code to `$response` like so:

```
/* @var $response \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse */
print_r($response->getData(true));
```

then I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [ok] => 1
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => tom
            [1] => dick
            [2] => harry
        )

)
```

This has allowed me to create a test with a boundary drawn around the PHP, and no calls are made to the test box to interact with the user system.

I will next investigate whether my controller's constructor can be changed from a concrete implementation hint (`\App\Services\Users`) to an interface, so that my test implementation does not need to extend from the real one.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel "Feature" test you can mock (alter the normal binding) using the following:

```
use Mockery\MockInterface;

...

$this->mock(YourService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
           $mock
               ->shouldReceive('increase')  // Sample
               ->withArgs([1,4])            // Sample
               ->times(1)                   // Sample
               ->andReturn(3);              // Sample              
        });
```

Then you won't get the normal concrete implementation for "YourService" from Service Container, you will get the mocked one.