# Laravel + Mockery InvalidCountException

Tags: laravel, mockery

I am trying to mock [a class](https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed) to prevent it from having to call 3rd party apis. But when setting up the mock, it doesn't seem to affect the controller action. I did try replacing the `$this->postJson()` by manually creating instances of the `Request`- and `OEmbedController`-classes. The `create()`-method is getting called, but I am receiving an error from Mockery that it isn't.

What am I doing wrong here?

Error:

> Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException : Method create() from Mockery_2_Embed_Embed should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Test:

```
class OEmbedTest extends TestCase
{
    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    /**
     * It can return an OEmbed object
     * @test
     */
    public function it_can_return_an_o_embed_object()
    {
        $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hUIxyE2Ns8';

        Mockery::mock(Embed::class)
            ->shouldReceive('create')
            ->with($url)
            ->once();

        $response = $this->postJson(route('oembed', ['url' => $url]));
        $response->assertSuccessful();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $info = Embed::create($request->url);

    $providers = $info->getProviders();

    $oembed = $providers['oembed'];

    return response()
        ->json($oembed
            ->getBag()
            ->getAll());
}
```

Comment: You do not need to test the embed package; its already [tested](https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed/blob/master/tests/YoutubeTest.php), right?

Comment: Yes, so my thoughts were to mock the response form that class.

Comment: A tip: you can rename the `__invoke` method to `handle` it'll look nicer. You are *creating* an instance of Embed within the (invoke) method; thats untestable without the mock. I personally avoid mocking anything and resort to stubs / fake classes etc. I do recommend letting the Laravel build / create / instantiate the Embed object before it hits the controller. Which means creating a service provider which will take care of the instantiating the Embed object for you and perhaps placing it in the `$request` itself. Do add more info about route you are accessing.

Comment: So you are basically saying I should dependency inject the class? Like `$this->app->bind()`. Sure that is possible, but shouldn't it be possible without that? Because then I need an Interface, etc, which feels cumbersome for this little test.

Comment: You do not need an interface, just use `->bind(Embed\Embed::class, function($app){ return Embed\Embed::create($app['request']->url); });` Now I do not know whats going on after `create` is called. But in the controller you can now use `$info = resolve(Embed\Embed::class)`; obviously you need to do checking if request has url parameter etc (do this within the bind closure). Now in the test `setUp` you need to *rebind* it, for more information read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262576/how-to-mock-a-service-or-a-serviceprovider-when-running-feature-tests-in-larav/50263049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using this in my test:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    app()->instance(Embed::class, new FakeEmbed);
}
```

Then resolving it like this

```
$embed = resolve(Embed::class);
$embed = $embed->create($url);
```

Comment: So you created another class (FakeEmbed) for mocking?

Comment: Yes, that was the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mocking the `Embed` class the wrong way. If you use the Laravel facade method `shouldReceive()` instead of creating a Mock of the class itself, the framework will place the mock in the service container for you:

```
Embed::shouldReceive('create')
    ->with($url)
    ->once();
```

instead of

```
Mockery::mock(Embed::class)
    ->shouldReceive('create')
    ->with($url)
    ->once();
```

Also be aware that if the parameters your tested code passes to the mock differs from what you learned the mock with `with($url)`, the mock considers itself uncalled. But you'll receive another error for calling a not defined method anyway.

Comment: The `Embed` class isn't a Facade though. Its namespace is Embed\Embed.

Comment: So you are trying to mock a static method? I'm afraid that's not going to work.

Comment: Didn't know you can't mock static methods without using Facades.

Comment: That's actually a limitation of the mocking libraries, not Laravel. Facades only provide static access to methods; it doesn't mean the methods itself are static (in fact, they are never as far as I know). So the easiest way to achieve testability could be to build your own proxy class around it... (which doesn't use static methods).